# SQL Server Update via Select Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-update

I have the following sql statement and I want to update a field on the rows returned from the select statement.  Is this possible with my select?  The things I have tried are not giving me the desired results:

```
SELECT 
Flows_Flows.FlowID, 
Flows_Flows.Active, 
Flows_Flows.BeatID,
Flows_Flows.FlowTitle, 
Flows_Flows.FlowFileName, 
Flows_Flows.FlowFilePath, 
Flows_Users.UserName, 
Flows_Users.DisplayName, 
Flows_Users.ImageName,
Flows_Flows.Created, 
SUM(CASE WHEN [Like] = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Likes,  
SUM(CASE WHEN [Dislike] = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Dislikes 
FROM Flows_Flows 
INNER JOIN Flows_Users ON Flows_Users.UserID = Flows_Flows.UserID 
LEFT JOIN Flows_Flows_Likes_Dislikes ON          
Flows_Flows.FlowID=Flows_Flows_Likes_Dislikes.FlowID 
WHERE Flows_Flows.Active = '1' AND Flows_Flows.Created < DATEADD(day, -60, GETDATE())
Group By Flows_Flows.FlowID, Flows_Flows.Active, Flows_Flows.BeatID, 
Flows_Flows.FlowTitle, Flows_Flows.FlowFileName,  Flows_Flows.FlowFilePath,        
Flows_Users.UserName, Flows_Users.DisplayName, Flows_Users.ImageName,     
Flows_Flows.Created 
Having SUM(CASE WHEN [Like] = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = '0' AND SUM(CASE WHEN [Dislike] = 1              
THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >= '0'
```

This select statement returns exactly what I need but I want to change the Active field from  1 to 0.

Comment: Wait, you want to return An active field of zero?  Or you want to make the field zero in the database?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are asking, are you trying to update the "Active" field of the rows that fall in the SELECT statement from 1 to 0? So like performing a select and update in the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes - the general structure might be like this: (note you don't declare your primary key)

```
UPDATE mytable
set myCol = 1
where myPrimaryKey in (
select myPrimaryKey from mytable where interesting bits happen here )
```

Comment: Yup. Once you got your select query working, you basically just have to encapsulate it in a WHERE IN clause of an UPDATE statement, no matter how complex it is, but this time only returning the primary key.

Comment: I am starting to see this query style of `WHERE x IN (SELECT ... FROM ...)` as a database anti-pattern. While it may be easier to understand for simple queries, it breaks down **really fast** as soon as it gets even a tiny bit more complicated. Such as joining on two columns, or needing to join to a third table, or a fourth, on the same key (causing the `IN()` clause to be duplicated). So I mean no hostility at all but am just wondering and truly would like to understand--is there a reason you go for the IN() syntax rather than using a proper `INNER JOIN` or even a semi-join with `EXISTS`?

Comment: this is a case up UPDATE.  it specifically will require a single table so there is no concern of the joins at the outer layer.

Answer (score 0):

Because you haven't made your question more clear in what result you want to achieve, I'll provide an answer with my own assumptions.

**Assumption**

You have a select statement that gives you stuffs, and it works as desired. What you want it to do is to make it return results and update those selected rows on the fly - basically like saying "find X, tell me about X and make it Y".

**Anwser**

If my assumption is correct, unfortunately I don't think there is any way you can do that. A select does not alter the table, it can only fetch information. Similarly, an update does not provide more detail than the number of rows updated.

But don't give up yet, depending on the result you want to achieve, you have alternatives.

**Alternatives**

1. If you just want to update the rows that you have selected, you can
   simply write an UPDATE statement to do that, and @Randy has provided
   a good example of how it will be written.
2. If you want to reduce calls to server, meaning you want to make just
   one call to the server and get result, as well as to update the
   rows, you can write store procedures to do that.

Store procedures are like functions you wrote in programming languages. It essentially defines a set of sql operations and gives them a name. Each time you call that store procedure, the set of operations gets executed with supplied inputs, if any.

So if you want to learn more about store procedures you can take a look at:
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/introduction-to-sql-stored-procedures.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are looking for a syntax to be able to select the value of Active to be 0 if it is 1. The syntax for something like that is

```
SELECT 
 Active= CASE WHEN Active=1 THEN 0 ELSE Active END
FROM
 <Tables>
WHERE
 <JOIN Conditions>
```